# Primefaces: Updating after action(-Listener) completed

Tags: java, primefaces-7.0

I want my p:datatable to update/refresh after I deleted an entry. Deletion on DB side succeeds. After a manual refresh, the entry is gone. But I can not get the p:datatable to refresh itself automatically

I aldready tried ajax commands, checking execution order and different update targets.

p:datatable from index.xhtml:

```java
<h:form id="form">
        <p:dataTable id="table" var="row" value="#{mitarbeiterView.mitarbeiter}">
            <p:column headerText="ID">
                <h:outputText value="#{row.employeeId}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Name">
                <h:outputText value="#{row.lastname}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Löschen">
                <p:commandLink update=":form, :form:table" action="#{mitarbeiterService.deleteEmployee(mitarbeiterView.selectedEmployee)}" 
                        title="Löschen" styleClass="ui-icon pi pi-trash">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{row}" target="#{mitarbeiterView.selectedEmployee}" />
                </p:commandLink>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

MitarbeiterView.java:

```java
@Named(value = "mitarbeiterView")
@ViewScoped
public class MitarbeiterView implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7924178697538784022L;

    private List<Employee> mitarbeiter;
    private Employee selectedEmployee;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        SessionConfig.initSession();
        mitarbeiter = Queries.findAllEmployees();
    }

    public List<Employee> getMitarbeiter() {
        return mitarbeiter;
    }

    public void setMitarbeiter(List<Employee> mitarbeiter) {
        this.mitarbeiter = mitarbeiter;
    }

    public void setSelectedEmployee(Employee selectedEmployee) {
        this.selectedEmployee = selectedEmployee;
    }

    public Employee getSelectedEmployee() {
        return selectedEmployee;
    }
}
```

MitarbeiterService.java```

```java
@Named(value = "mitarbeiterService")
@ViewScoped
public class MitarbeiterService implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -445070832052637147L;

    public void deleteEmployee(Employee mitarbeiter) {
        if (mitarbeiter != null) {
            ManageEmployees.deleteEmployee(mitarbeiter.getEmployeeId());
        }
    }
```

The p:datatable should refresh itself. The deleted employee should be gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you must just delete the `selectedEmployee` from your `List<Employee>` (`mitarbeiter`) .
You can do the query again in the backend after delete  or just remove the  `selectedEmployee` from your list. You must do this in method `deleteEmployee`

I think that `deleteEmployee` must be in the `MitarbeiterView` ManageBean. If you put the  `deleteEmployee` in the `MitarbeiterView` ManageBean you can do somethink like this:

```
public void deleteEmployee(Employee mitarbeiter) {
    if (mitarbeiter != null) {
        ManageEmployees.deleteEmployee(mitarbeiter.getEmployeeId());
        mitarbeiter = Queries.findAllEmployees();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, sorry. Same behavior :(
I replaced ` action="#{mitarbeiterService.deleteEmployee(mitarbeiterView.selectedEmployee)}" ` with `action="#{mitarbeiterService.deleteEmployee(row)}" ` and deleted `f:setPropertyActionListener` but did not change anything.

Comment: Can you add the delete method in your question?

Comment: I did not say to do that. I said to add for example the `mitarbeiter = Queries.findAllEmployees();` after the delete in the delete method

Comment: I think that your approach is not very good. My opinion is that you must make one manage bean.I don't think that you must put the Manage bean as parameter.

Comment: Thought so too. See the Update in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, new Answer. The comment-editor just looks rubish.

Thanks, this worked. The delete methode now looks like this:

```java
    public void deleteEmployee(Employee mitarbeiter, MitarbeiterView view) {
        if (mitarbeiter != null) {
            ManageEmployees.deleteEmployee(mitarbeiter.getEmployeeId());

            view.setMitarbeiter(Queries.findAllEmployees());
        }
    }
```

and the p:column

```java
            <p:column headerText="Löschen">
                <p:commandLink update=":form, :form:table" action="#{mitarbeiterService.deleteEmployee(row, mitarbeiterView)}" 
                        title="Löschen" styleClass="ui-icon pi pi-trash"/>
            </p:column>
```

Forgot that I do not work on the live entities. Happens when a Life-long BACKend Developer has to design the FRONTend ;)

Update:
The code would look nicer if I add an init method, binding the MitarbeiterView to a static variable. Passing to the method is just dirty and ugly.